# Problema al cargar los datos json en un datatable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, datatable

Buenas tardes, por favor su apoyo, al insertar los datos de un json en php a hacia un datatable no me muestra, he validado y los datos si son cargados en el php pero al jalarlos a un datatable no los muestra.

mi código getjson.php

```
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

$posts = array();
$query = ("SELECT * FROM user");

$stmt = $db_con->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $posts['datos'][] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($posts);
```

este es el script que tengo en mi index.php jalando con e $.ajax los datos que tengo el getjson.php, pero no logro que sean mostrados.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
                url: 'getjson.php',
                dataType: 'json',
            })

    $.each(data.datos, function(i,post){
            var newRow =
            "<tr>"
            +"<td>"+post.login+"</td>"
            +"<td>"+post.email+"</td>"
            +"</tr>";
            $(newRow).appendTo("#json-data tbody");
        });
        $('#json-data').DataTable();
    });
```

hice unas pruebas reemplazando el $.ajax por datos temporales y los muestra sin ningun problema.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var data = {
    'datos':
    [
        {'login':'si', 'email':'probandp@test.com'},
        {'login':'si', 'email':'probandp@test.com'}
    ]
};           

$.each(data.datos, function(i,post){
    var newRow =
      "<tr>"
       +"<td>"+post.login+"</td>"
       +"<td>"+post.email+"</td>"
       +"</tr>";
     $(newRow).appendTo("#json-data tbody");
   });
  $('#json-data').DataTable();
});
```

Su apoyo indicandome en que me estoy equivocando al jalar y mostra los datos del getjson.php dentro del $.ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El posible error es que no gestiona la respuesta de la petición `Ajax` por lo tanto la variable `data` no existe y mucho menos `data.datos`.

Para la llamada `Ajax` con éxito sería conveniente emplear `done` *(exito de la llamada)*

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getjson.php',
        dataType: 'json',
    })
    .done(function(data){
        $.each(data.datos, function(i,post){
            var newRow =
            "<tr>"
            +"<td>"+post.login+"</td>"
            +"<td>"+post.email+"</td>"
            +"</tr>";
            $(newRow).appendTo("#json-data tbody");
        });
    });
    $('#json-data').DataTable();
});
```

También podría haber pasado un `array` de configuración a `DataTables` y que este se encargue de añadir las filas directamente.

**HTML**

```
<table id="json-data">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Login</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('#json-data').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "ajax": {
          "url": "getjson.php", 
          "dataSrc": "datos" //indice del array retornado
       },
        "columns": [ // Aquí los nombres de las columnas que devuelve PHP
            { "data": "login" },
            { "data": "email" },
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS !!! Genial, ahora entendí el porqué no estaba llamando. nuevamente muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Mientras qe se realiza tu lamda AJAX, se ejecuta el `each` porque AJAX realiza una llamada asíncrona. Una solución sería meter el `each` dentro de la función `success` de la función `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'getjson.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (datos) {

        $.each(data.datos, function(i,post){
            var newRow =
            "<tr>"
            +"<td>"+post.login+"</td>"
            +"<td>"+post.email+"</td>"
            +"</tr>";
            $(newRow).appendTo("#json-data tbody");
        });

        $('#json-data').DataTable();


    }
});
```